# Issue Regarding KL Divergence in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, signal-processing, sensors

I have posted earlier also regarding KL divergence query but unfortunately did not received a reply may be due to the complexity of my question so I have tried to explain my problem by using simple example.

I have one reference sensor signal and 1 measured value of some sensor.

I want to find out the error or difference between Ref and Measured sensor signal Values.

SO I am using KL divergence.

First I normalized my reference and sensor signal histogram and then applied KL divergence.

My data is too much and complicated means it contains a lot of zeroes and negative values and also 0.001 like these values also.

I was applying KL divergence but unfortunately was not being able to get some good results so I was wondering that may be I did not able to get the good concept of KL divergence or I am doing wrong at some point in The code.

It will nice of people if someone help me out in this. I shall be grateful.

I have also seen a post explaining KL divergence and had a look at it but some concepts remained missing so I am posting my example along with query.

Am i on right way or there is some fault in my concepts .

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
      ref = [5 6 7 5 8 7 8 9 -2 -3 -4];
      measured_sensor = [3 3 4 5 7 8 9 9 -1 -2 -3];

   %normalized histograms for 
   C= hist( ref);
   C1 = C ./ sum(C);
   D = hist(measured_sensor);

   D1 = D ./ sum(D);

  figure(1)
  ax11=subplot(321);
  bar(C1)

  ax12=subplot(322);
  bar(D1)

  d = zeros(size(C1));

  goodIdx = C1>0 & D1>0;

  d1 = sum(C1(goodIdx) .* log(C1(goodIdx) ./ D1(goodIdx)))

  d2 = sum(D1(goodIdx) .* log(D1(goodIdx) ./ C1(goodIdx)))

  d(goodIdx) = d1 + d2
```

[image]

**Mean Based Gaussian Hysterisis (Means Error Finding)**

```
  ref = [5 6 7 5 8 7 8 9 -2 -3 -4];
  measured_sensor = [3 3 4 5 7 8 9 9 -1 -2 -3];

 sig_diff = ref - measured_sensor ;

 m = mean(sig_diff)
 deviation = std(sig_diff);

 pos = sig_diff(sig_diff>0)
 neg = sig_diff(sig_diff<0)

 m_pos = mean(pos)
 m_neg = mean (neg)

 hysterisis = abs( m_pos)+ abs(m_neg)

 figure(6) 
 ax11=subplot(321);
 histfit(sig_diff)

hold on
plot([m  m],[0 5000],'r')
plot([m-deviation  m-deviation],[0 5000],'r')
plot([m+deviation  m+deviation],[0 5000],'r')
hold off
```

The error value or Hysterisis value that I am getting with mean based Gaussian Distribution is  3.2500.

So I am expecting the error values from KL divergence near to 3.2500 value or in the range with some tolerance is also accepted.

Actually I am confused about these techniques that which one is giving me more precise version of error and with which technique i will get the best results.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, you say you got not good results, what does that mean exactly? What is a bad result and what would be a good result?

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for ur reply . 
Actually for my data set when I am applying this above mentioned algo the results that I want means I want the value of error between Ref and measured valued signal so it should be one value and the value which I am expecting in my case for my real data is around 1.140 but when I apply the above mentioned technique so it is not providing me accurate results.
I want to find out the amount of error between Ref and measured signal so I was confused in my implementation that whether I am on right way.

Comment: The results for the above example are in the attached picture so can u please provide me an idea that whether I am right or on wrong way.
I shall be really grateful and if u still find my clarification unclear please let me know I will try to make it simpler.

Comment: Matias Valdenegro please have a look at the updates . I hope it ill be easy to relate for understanding . Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don’t you just use Euclidean distance? Error = `norm(measured - reference)`? KL divergence is defined on probability *distributions*, not real data, and though sometimes you can convert data to distributions if you have a ton of samples, you don’t have a ton of samples here, so the KL divergence seems the wrong tool.

Comment: Ahmed Fasih I have tons of sample data originally this was just an example to have a look at the correctness of technique that whether i m on right way. I also tried to use RMSE but it did not worked well for me as it is good for finding large errors.

Comment: So thats why i shifted toward KL divergence. This was just an example to make my question simpler